# How do I add two currencies together?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am fairly new to programming. I am making a program where you enter a number into a textbox and when you leave the textbox, it converts your number to currency. I have also added another textbox which does the same.

This is what I want to happen:

```
If TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text =< 10,000 Then 
Sum = 10,000
Else
Sum = TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text
```

However, (i think) because I am converting the numbers to currency before I add them together, it always returns 10,000 no matter what.

I know there is probably something pretty obvious I am missing. If you need any clarification, just ask! I appreciate your help.

Comment: start by converting the text (string) to a numeric.  `TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text` wont always result in what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` concatenates strings, so `TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text` is a string and comparing it to the integer 10000 doesn't do what you want.

I would look for a text box control that lets you display numbers with a given format, but also gives you access to the numerical value as a property. Then you could add the values together without having to do a type conversion that may not work on your formatted currency string.

[MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) might give you some of that, but it's been a long time since I've used it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert String values to Double (or any other numeric type), before adding them up.

```
Dim tbSum as Double = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) + CDbl(Textbox2.Text)
If tbSum =< 10000 Then Sum = 10000 Else Sum = tbSum
```